# How to call different URLs in Python for load testing?

Tags: python, arrays, list, load

I have a code that perform load testing against any specific url. But I have to do load testing of a web service that has different URLs. To do so, I need to make an array of URLs and each thread should hit all the URLs given in an array. How can I do this? This is my code:

```
import httplib2

import socket

import time

from threading import Event
from threading import Thread
from threading import current_thread
from urllib import urlencode

# Modify these values to control how the testing is done

# How many threads should be running at peak load.
NUM_THREADS = 50

# How many minutes the test should run with all threads active.
TIME_AT_PEAK_QPS = 20 # minutes

# How many seconds to wait between starting threads.
# Shouldn't be set below 30 seconds.
DELAY_BETWEEN_THREAD_START = 30 # seconds

quitevent = Event()

def threadproc():
    """This function is executed by each thread."""
    print "Thread started: %s" % current_thread().getName()
    h = httplib2.Http(timeout=30)
    while not quitevent.is_set():
        try:
            # HTTP requests to exercise the server go here
            # !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            resp, content = h.request(
                "http://www.google.com")
            if resp.status != 200:
             print "Response not OK"
            # !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        except socket.timeout:
            pass

print "Thread finished: %s" % current_thread().getName()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    runtime = (TIME_AT_PEAK_QPS * 60 + DELAY_BETWEEN_THREAD_START * NUM_THREADS)
    print "Total runtime will be: %d seconds" % runtime
    threads = []
    try:
        for i in range(NUM_THREADS):
            t = Thread(target=threadproc)
            t.start()
            threads.append(t)
            time.sleep(DELAY_BETWEEN_THREAD_START)
        print "All threads running"
        time.sleep(TIME_AT_PEAK_QPS*60)
        print "Completed full time at peak qps, shutting down threads"
    except:
        print "Exception raised, shutting down threads"
quitevent.set()
time.sleep(3)
for t in threads:
    t.join(1.0)
print "Finished"
```

Comment: You haven't explained what is wrong with what you have. Do you have any errors? Are you results not as expected?

Comment: If you really are load testing a server (or servers) I would recommend using a tool that's designed for the purpose. One I have used successfully is the open source Apache Jmeter (http://jmeter.apache.org/).

Comment: I would additionally recommend using tsung for load testing (http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing a `threadproc` to `Thread`, extend the class:

```
class Worker(Thread):
    def __init__(self, urls):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.urls = urls

    def run(self):
        for url in self.urls:
            self.fetch(url)
```

That said, unless you do this to get a better understanding of threading and how load testing works internally, I suggest to use a mature testing framework like [Jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) instead. Years of experience went into it which you'd have to accumulate, first.

Comment: Actually I am beginner in python, the class that you explained is well  understandable but I dont know where in code I have to mention all the urls against that load testing is performed. You can see only one url mentioned in the code                                  resp, content = h.request("http://www.google.com") but how i give it  to multiple urls?

Comment: Move `threadproc` into the new class `Worker`, give it the parameters `self, url` and then replace `h.request("google.com")` with `h.request(url)`

Comment: Thanx, but where I have to define the array of urls. such as example.com, example.com/1,example.com/2....